# Accounting for a single row in variable range?

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic

So, I've been using various bits of code from various forums to put together macros to make my job easier, however I've hit a snag. I'm using the following bit of code to autofill and select a dynamic range that needs copying and pasting elsewhere:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("AP2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AP2:AP" & lastRow)
Range("AQ2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AQ2:AQ" & lastRow)
Range("AR2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AR2:AR" & lastRow)
Range("AS2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AS2:AS" & lastRow)
Range("AT2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AT2:AT" & lastRow)
Range("AU2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AU2:AU" & lastRow)

Range("AP2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

The issue I face is, I believe, in the last line (although I'm sure somebody will tell me there's an easier way to address lines 3-8). In the instances where this variable range returns a single row, the `Selection.End(xlDown)` grabs all rows from row 2 to the bottom, meaning it's too large to paste into the destination. How could I amend this to account for single rows?

FYI the `Selection.End(xlToRight)` is always the same number of columns, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want just to select range AP:AU from the second to the last row, just:

```
Range(Range("AP2"), Range("AU" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Select
```

BTW. I suspect that next thing that you want to do is Selection.Copy. Don't do that, just replace .Select with .Copy.

```
Range(Range("AP2"), Range("AU" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
```